# What does incoming constraint mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the ***incoming constraints*** are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

## Question

What does the incoming constraint mean in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google's flutter documentation on understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints):

> A widget gets its own constraints from its parent [the "incoming constraint" you are asking about]. A constraint is just a set of 4 doubles: a minimum and maximum width, and a minimum and maximum height.
> Then the widget goes through its own list of children. One by one, the widget tells its children what their constraints are (which can be different for each child), and then asks each child what size it wants to be.
> Then, the widget positions its children (horizontally in the x axis, and vertically in the y axis), one by one.
> And, finally, the widget tells its parent about its own size (within the original constraints, of course).

I suggest you read that entire URL for more details.  The Google people are writing some amazingly clear documentation.